# How can i disable Pageant in Putty in command line?

Tags: putty, keepass

I open SSH links in Putty from KeePass (with KeeAgent plugin).

One of servers I visit show authentication error immediately after connection, because putty tries to use private key authentication.

Is there command line parameter to disable key authentication in Putty?

I know, I can uncheck this box and save it in "Default Settings". But I wold like to define this for individual entries.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Manual page](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-agentauth) describes options to control use of Pageant for authentication:

> The `-agent` option turns on SSH authentication using Pageant, and `-noagent` turns it off. These options are only meaningful if you are using SSH.

So now urls to this servers in KeePass looks like `ssh://{IP} -noagent`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PuTTY manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7) you cannot change this behaviour from the command line.

What you could do, create a saved session for this particular host without the checkbox set and launch the saved session from the command line with `putty.exe -load "session name"`

Comment: Documentation you linked is outdated. Version 0.53b is released in 2002. Current version is 0.63.